# Openstack Neutron vpnaas issue

Tags: linux, site-to-site-vpn, openstack-neutron

Not able to use multiple PSK with one router in Openstack neutron.

First IPsec tunnel from neutron router works fine, however, when I create another tunnel to another site with different PSK, the tunnel does not come up, until neutron services are re-started.

Multiple tunnels with same PSK works fine, without restarting neutron services.

I have tried this with different versions of Openstack: Yoga, Wallaby and 2023.2 Bobcat, deployed with Kolla-ansible on Ubuntu.

Bobcat deployed with Kolla-ansible 17.0.1, Yoga deployed with Kolla-ansible 14.10.1

I have only enabled VPNaas in globals.yml.

Am I missing something?